# Set Sender Name in Gmail API (WITHOUT GETTING WARNING)

Tags: python, api, email, gmail, gmail-api

The problem I am facing is that

1. If I add message['from'] in attribute in the create_message function then after sending Gmail shows a warning ("Be careful with this message - gmail could not verify that it actually came from .

The solution to the above problem is to remove message['from'] attribute as it automatically retrieves the details from creds config file. Once I remove the from attribute, the warning goes away.

2. If I remove the message['from'] attribute, I am not able to set the Sender's Name ("ABC NAME" abcname@gmail.com.
   Hence mail goes like abcname@gmail.com instead of ABC Name

Looking for a way through which I can achieve both the things.

Create Function looks like this

```
def create_message(sender, to, cc, subject, message_text):
message = MIMEText(message_text,'html')
message['to'] = to
message['from'] = sender
message['subject'] = subject
if str(cc) !='nan':
    message['cc'] = cc

pprint(message)
return {
    'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(
        bytes(
            message.as_string(),
            "utf-8")).decode("utf-8")}
```